# maven external libraries - jar files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I would like to add external java libraries to a Maven project using intellij. I followed previous discussions in stackoverflow but none of those work for me. I added jar files to the libraries and source code can detect them but when I try to compile my project (mvn package), it gives me "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: Have you specified these libraries as dependencies in Maven pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add external jar you can use system scope . Like:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>..</artifactId>
    <groupId>..</groupId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dependency.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

[its not suggested](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)
but 
[you can also install your jar in the repository.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project/22300875)

```
 mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
   -DgroupId=<group-id> \
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
   -Dversion=<version> \
   -Dpackaging=<packaging> \
   -DgeneratePom=true
```